# Shared data queue between processes

Tags: c, multithreading, process, queue, ipc

I have a C program that currently uses multiple threads to process data. I use a glib GAsyncQueue for the producer threads to send their data to consumer threads. Now I need to move the threads into into independent processes and I'm not sure how to proceed with pushing data between them. Using pipes does not seem to be very suitable to my task since the amount data being pushed is rather large. Another option is to obtain a piece of shared memory but, since calculating an upper bound on the amount of shared data is a little difficult, this option is less than attractive.

Do you know of something like GAsyncQueue that can be used with multiple processes? Since I'm already using glib, I prefer to use its facilities, but I'm open to using other libraries if they provide what I need.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX specifies a `msgsnd(2)`, `msgget(2)` interface, though the message and queue sizes may be smaller than you wish. (Linux allows you to modify the sizes with the `/proc/sys/kernel/msgmax` and `/proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb` tunable files; the defaults are 8k and 16k.)

Since message buses are a fairly common need you may wish to pick something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html), which provides prewritten bindings to many languages and may make future development easier.

Comment: Do you know how RabbitMQ performs under load? Can it handle, say, a few hundred megabytes per second worth of thousands of messages?